# Current Notepad++ Color Scheme

Tags: notepad++

Does Notepad++ show which color scheme (or which language's color scheme) it's currently using? Under the Language menu, there is no "tick" for any of the languages so I can't be sure what color scheme is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does show which language is being used, but only if that language exists under the 'C' group. This is clearly a bug.

I am using v6.6.9, the most recent release.

[image: SQL]
[image]

Comment: Thanks - I am using v6.7.2 and see the same behavior.